# Css to right align two boxes one above the other

Tags: css

I've inherited a design where an image is aligned with the right hand side of the viewport using "float:right".  Now I'd like to add some tagline text either above or below that image, which will also align with the right hand side of the viewport.  I must not understand the box model whatsover and/or how to use float, because my efforts result in the tagline and image rendering next to one another, or the image left-aligned with the beginning of the tagline.

Below is my CSS that right aligns just the tagline.  Thanks in advance.

```
<div style="margin:5px; float:right;">
    <p>dexygen: Powering the Desk Wide Web</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for reminding me about clear.  I'd read about this in the second chapter of CSS Mastery earlier this month.  Will try things out and accept an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put `<div style="clear: both";></div>` after your image :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `clear:right;` to your `<div>` to force it to clear it and display beneath it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `clear: both` on the image to not allow anything besides it. Otherwise, can't you just float a div with the image and the `<p>`-tagline (or use a `<br>`? That should put them on separate lines.